# Is browser side resizing ok performance wise?

Tags: html, image, performance

Is it okay to set the width and height of the `img` tag performance wise knowing that the original image is much smaller?

The articles I've read usually say that setting width and height solves the performance issues, but its not clear, if I set the width and height and they are different from the native image size, is it "ok"?

Or Do I have to always set the same width and height as the image itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have benchmarks at hand, but I think it won't be a problem at all if you set a width/height different than the original one. The browser renders the image, and that's it. The rendering action is usually not expensive in terms of performance AFAIK. By the way you are not supposed to be afraid of things like this, unless you are doing something very fancy (i.e. an image 99999x99999 or rendering 2,000 images in a single page).

Anyway, if you can avoid that, it's probably better.

Comment: thanks for your answer is it also alright to use % width and height?

Comment: no, it isn't. Width and height attributes must be specified in pixels, as per the [W3C's HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/embedded-content-0.html#width-0).

Answer (score 2):

Unless you're anticipating your site used on slow/limited devices like smartphones you shouldn't bother about performance in this specific case.

However, if you specify size that is larger than the actual image size then the image will look bad.

From my experience specifying an image size is useful to avoid page layout change when an image is not loaded immediately; in this case the browser initially doesn't know what the size will be and won't reserve the needed space for it. Later when the image is loaded the page contents may "jump" because the size of the image will change for the browser.